# Must declare the scalar variable "@FieldDataFileName_ID"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting these errors upon executing the procedure. Anybody has any idea why? `@FieldDataFileName_ID` seems to be declared before usage.

The procedure was copied from another database, and it worked fine there. But after creating and running the procedure in a new database this error popped.

```
(12 rows affected)
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@FieldDataFileName_ID".
```

This is the source code

```
USE [GEA-WellDiagram]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_CaptureWellDiagram]    Script Date: 2020-03-18 11:07:01 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CaptureWellDiagram] 

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FileName nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @FolderPath nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @FieldDataRow_ID int
    DECLARE @FieldDataFileName_ID nvarchar (40)
    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @files table (ID int IDENTITY, FileName varchar(100))
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @FolderPath = N'C:\PowerBIData\WellDiagram'
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @FolderPath + ' /b'
    SET @FieldDataRow_ID = 111
    SET @FieldDataFileName_ID = 'GS_01-WDiag.png'
    insert into @files execute xp_cmdshell  @cmd

    DECLARE  Files cursor for
    SELECT FileName from  @files
    WHERE isnull(FileName,'')<>''

    OPEN Files

       FETCH NEXT FROM Files
       INTO @FileName
       EXEC  [dbo].[usp_ImportWellDiag]
        @ImageFolderPath = @FolderPath,
        @FileName=@FileName, 
        @FieldDataRow_ID = @FieldDataRow_ID,
        @FieldDataFileName_ID = @FieldDataFileName_ID
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
          FETCH NEXT FROM Files 
          INTO  @FileName
          EXEC  [dbo].[usp_ImportWellDiag]
            @ImageFolderPath = @FolderPath,
            @Filename=@FileName, 
            @FieldDataRow_ID = @FieldDataRow_ID,
            @FieldDataFileName_ID = @FieldDataFileName_ID
       END
       close Files
       deallocate Files
END
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  Do you have `@FieldDataFileName_ID` as your third parameter of your sp `usp_ImportWellDiag`?

Answer (score -1):

Your are calling another SP, `[dbo].[usp_ImportWellDiag]`, check it in case that variable is declared.

It seems that it doesn't care, but I suggest to change the name of the variable `@FieldDataFileName_ID` to `@FieldDataFileName_ID_X`, that avoid ambiguous cases.

Also if you can add the code of the other SP that it was called.

Comment: this is the sp, it has some commented code, was supposed to switch alter with created and run the query                                                                                                                 `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CaptureWellDiagram] 

AS
BEGIN
 --One time only after that you can comment------------------
 --SET NOCOUNT ON;
 --EXEC
 --sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
 --GO
 --RECONFIGURE
 --GO
 --sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
 --GO
 --RECONFIGURE`